# convert factor into date with right days

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a list of data.frames. Each data.frame has one column with dates and other with values. This is a sample of one of the data.frame (the data is quite large)

```
           dput(mydata)
structure(list(date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1993-01-01", 
"1993-02-01", "1993-03-01", "1993-04-01", "1993-05-01", "1993-06-01", 
"1993-07-01", "1993-08-01", "1993-09-01", "1993-10-01", "1993-11-01", 
"1993-12-01", "1994-01-01", "1994-02-01", "1994-03-01", "1994-04-01", 
"1994-05-01", "1994-06-01", "1994-07-01", "1994-08-01", "1994-09-01", 
"1994-10-01", "1994-11-01", "1994-12-01", "1995-01-01", "1995-02-01", 
"1995-03-01", "1995-04-01", "1995-05-01", "1995-06-01", "1995-07-01", 
"1995-08-01", "1995-09-01", "1995-10-01", "1995-11-01", "1995-12-01", 
"1996-01-01", "1996-02-01", "1996-03-01", "1996-04-01", "1996-05-01", 
"1996-06-01", "1996-07-01", "1996-08-01", "1996-09-01", "1996-10-01", 
"1996-11-01", "1996-12-01", "2000-01-01", "2000-02-01", "2000-03-01", 
"2000-04-01", "2000-05-01", "2000-06-01", "2000-07-01", "2000-08-01", 
"2000-09-01", "2000-10-01", "2000-11-01", "2000-12-01", "2001-01-01", 
"2001-02-01", "2001-03-01", "2001-04-01", "2001-05-01", "2001-06-01", 
"2001-07-01", "2001-08-01", "2001-09-01", "2001-10-01", "2001-11-01", 
"2001-12-01", "2002-01-01", "2002-02-01", "2002-03-01", "2002-04-01", 
"2002-05-01", "2002-06-01", "2002-07-01", "2002-08-01", "2002-09-01", 
"2002-10-01", "2002-11-01", "2002-12-01", "2003-01-01", "2003-02-01", 
"2003-03-01", "2003-04-01", "2003-05-01", "2003-06-01", "2003-07-01", 
"2003-08-01", "2003-09-01", "2003-10-01", "2003-11-01", "2003-12-01"
), class = "factor"), value = c(32, 33.75, 23, 15.125, 25.125, 
25.857, 25.25, 38.125, 35.5, 49.875, 55.25, 46.625, 52.625, 51.125, 
45.75, 52.625, 54.125, 42.875, 36.375, 39.375, 52.625, 61.375, 
61.375, 61.875, 61.5, 62.5, 50.625, 43.5, 38.167, 36.714, 41.875, 
28.875, 20.333, 22.25, 24, 21.333, 3.167, 41.75, 19.375, 10.25, 
16.625, 19.5, 48.333, 22.5, 26.25, 28.625, 31.5, 50.625, 50.375, 
57, 63, 64.286, 65, 46.125, 59, 54.75, 25.375, 77, 74.125, -99, 
-99, -99, 95.375, 86, 72.875, 85.25, 38.5, -99, 72.875, 80.375, 
99.25, 94, 76.5, 32.875, 87.375, 114.875, 91.5, 96.25, 64.25, 
55.75, 67.5, 79, 103, 66.25, 50.143, 79.5, 66.25, 75.75, 73.125, 
77.25, 70.125, 65.5, 77.375, 103.375, 97.25, 66.875, 86.875, 
71.375, 69.875, 62.75)), .Names = c("date", "value"), row.names = c(1L, 
97L, 193L, 289L, 385L, 481L, 577L, 673L, 769L, 865L, 961L, 1057L, 
1153L, 1249L, 1345L, 1441L, 1537L, 1633L, 1729L, 1825L, 1921L, 
2017L, 2113L, 2209L, 2305L, 2401L, 2497L, 2593L, 2689L, 2785L, 
2881L, 2L, 98L, 194L, 290L, 386L, 482L, 578L, 674L, 770L, 866L, 
962L, 1058L, 1154L, 1250L, 1346L, 1442L, 1538L, 1634L, 1730L, 
1826L, 1922L, 2018L, 2114L, 2210L, 2306L, 2402L, 2498L, 2594L, 
2690L, 2786L, 2882L, 3L, 99L, 195L, 291L, 387L, 483L, 579L, 675L, 
771L, 867L, 963L, 1059L, 1155L, 1251L, 1347L, 1443L, 1539L, 1635L, 
1731L, 1827L, 1923L, 2019L, 2115L, 2211L, 2307L, 2403L, 2499L, 
2595L, 2691L, 2787L, 2883L, 4L, 100L, 196L, 292L, 388L, 484L, 
580L), class = "data.frame")
```

The problem is that the column date is a factor and all months contain 31 days (the corresponding value has -99 is the month is 30 or 28,29-days). I am trying to convert the date into a proper date format, with the correct days, but I'm struggling with that..I can convert the factor to a date, but I don't know how to convert into the right days like:

```
      head(mydata)
      date  value 
      1993-01-01 32.000
      1993-01-02 33.750
      1993-01-03 23.000
      1993-01-04 15.125
      1993-01-05 25.125
      1993-01-06 25.857
```

....

I appreciate any suggestion,
Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell us what you have done so far?

Comment: Does each row represent to one and only one date, and for a month with 30 days, are there 30 rows with the first day of the month in the date variable?  Also, does each data frame contain one and only one month's data? Finally, are the rows in actual date order (i.e. first row with 1993-01-01 is January 1, second row with 1993-01-01 is actually January 2, etc.)?

Comment: provide some data with `dput(yourData)`

Comment: Yes, each row represent one date and the problem it's that for each year I do have 12 months but all months have 31 days, so the column with values have -99 in those months that do not have 31 days..My problem is that I don't know how to convert in an artificial way each month with the corresponding proper days. The dates are in order, i.e. 1993-01-01 is January 1, 1993-01-01 is January 2 and so on... Thanks!

Comment: I just edited the question adding a sample of my data, thanks!

Comment: What do you want done with the 31st of February? You've also not given any examples of that in your data. So what are we supposed to do? Show us how converting to character and then to date doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. I filtered out the `value` with `-99` through the process, assuming that this is what you want to do.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

mydata2 <- mydata %>%
  mutate(date = as.character(date)) %>%                       # Convert to character
  filter(value != -99) %>%                                    # Remove -99
  extract(date, into = c("Year", "Month", "Day"),             # Split the date column
          regex = "([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)-([0-1]+)", 
          convert = TRUE) %>%    
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%                                   # Group by Year and Month
  mutate(Day = Day + row_number() - 1) %>%                    # Update Day to Day + row numbers - 1
  unite(col = date, Year, Month, Day, sep = "-") %>%          # Unite the Year, Month, Day columns
  mutate(date = as.Date(date))                                # Convert the date to date class
head(mydata2)
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#         date  value
#       <date>  <dbl>
# 1 1993-01-01 32.000
# 2 1993-01-02 33.750
# 3 1993-01-03 23.000
# 4 1993-01-04 15.125
# 5 1993-01-05 25.125
# 6 1993-01-06 25.857
```

Or we can use the `dplyr` and `lubridate` package with a similar strategy.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

mydata2 <- mydata %>%
  filter(value != -99) %>%                            # Remove -99
  mutate(date = ymd(as.character(date))) %>%          # Convert the date column to date class
  mutate(Year = year(date), Month = month(date)) %>%  # Create Year and Month column
  group_by(Year, Month) %>%                           # Group by Year and Month
  mutate(date = date + days(row_number() - 1)) %>%    # Add day numbers based on row number - 1
  ungroup() %>%                                       # Ungroup
  select(date, value)                                 # Select the columns
head(mydata2)
# # A tibble: 6 x 2
#         date  value
#       <date>  <dbl>
# 1 1993-01-01 32.000
# 2 1993-01-02 33.750
# 3 1993-01-03 23.000
# 4 1993-01-04 15.125
# 5 1993-01-05 25.125
# 6 1993-01-06 25.857
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice way! It works fine, although I did a change, because I have some -99 also for missing values in particular cases (e.g. 3 January ..)..but it's working even if I don't filter the -99. After applying the rest of the strategy, I just have to remove the NA and it seems that works fine. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to know it works. And I think you did a great job to remove the NA in your dataset.